# discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: extension is a required argument that is missing

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

Main.py

```
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHlGf.png)
```

Bot.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os

intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!", intents=intents)
client.remove_command("help")


@client.command()
async def load(ctx, extension):
    if ctx.author.id == 569942050145828864:
        client.load_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")
        await ctx.send("Коги загружени...")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Иди нахуй!")


@client.command()
async def unload(ctx, extension):
    if ctx.author.id == 569942050145828864:
        client.unload_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")
        await ctx.send("Коги вигружени...")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Иди нахуй!")


@client.command()
async def reload(ctx, extension):
    if ctx.author.id == 569942050145828864:
        client.unload_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")
        client.load_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")
        await ctx.send("Коги перезагружени...")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Иди нахуй!")


for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
    if filename.endswith(".py"):
        client.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")


client.run("*")
```

Error:

```
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pxqB.png)
```

Can you help me? I already tried to reinstall discord.
And also it does not accept commands. Is it because I can't load the logs?
Can please anyone help me?
If you need more details from me, just say it.
The bot starts and works stably.

Comment: Please don't provide code as pictures. Thank you and welcome to stackoverflow!

Comment: You need to pass an argument to call commands that have additional parameters after ctx. For example `!load user` if `user` was the name of the module. Since the extension argument is required, calling `!load` by itself would cause MissingRequiredArgument.